# Difference between tags "income-tax" and "income-taxes"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There is an tag [income-taxes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-taxes). I see few [question tagged](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-taxes) with this.
We already have a very popular tag [income-tax](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-tax) .

We already have a plural generic tag [taxes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) and it doesn't make sense to have additional tag [income-taxes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-taxes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we should merge them. Seems pretty clear-cut.

As it's hard to reverse afterwards I'll leave it a couple of days before doing that.

EDIT: now done.

Answer (score 3):

[income-taxes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-taxes) has 19 questions vs 1649 for [income-tax](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-tax). I don't see the need for the former.

I'll agree with Ganesh, it's good practice to give these things a few days for member input. Although, Meta doesn't get as much activity as we'd like.

Update - Done.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that you're going to get any push-back on a merge this time. The case for this one is stronger than my investing/investment suggestion.

Comment: @NathanL Just for fun, I was trying to think of *any* argument against the merge, and I couldn't.

Comment: @TTT - And as members requested, with no objection from me, I gave it nearly a week before doing anything I couldn't undo.